# How to make square (or round) floating activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

How to make square (or round) floating activty? There's a variant with system alert window, but I don't think it's a good idea. Is there any ways to do this customizing dialog theme?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dialog fragment. It is highly customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Use DialogActivity & make your layout as per your round or square.
ref : URL

[Android custom dialog example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)

[Custom Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Set customized style would change the default corner of activity.