# How to show DialogFragment not form activty?

Tags: android

I'm in WidgetProvider where I got in [such way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748590/clickable-widgets-in-android). The only thing I've is context. And I need to show DialogFragment. To show it, I need to get FragmentManger, but where can I get it if I don't have activity?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. Fragments and dialogs have to be shown by an `Activity`. Call `startActivity()` to start up an activity that will show your `DialogFragment`.

Comment: Can this activity be invisible?

Comment: It's probably better that you create an Activity with a Dialog theme instead.

Comment: @danpetruk: I have never tried using `Theme.NoDisplay` with an activity that attempts to show a `DialogFragment` as a dialog. That might work. Otherwise, as BladeCoder suggests, you can create an activity that has a `...Dialog` theme, so that it will not fill the screen.

Comment: @BladeCoder I wanted to do this, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430665/how-to-make-square-or-round-floating-activity

Comment: @danpetruk You can for example extend `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog`and customize it. Take a look at AppCompat's theme files to see how they customized the design to provide a Material look on older Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

create a class which extends activity in onCreate create a dialog  and startActivity.

```
        Intent dialog = new Intent(context, Your_dialog.class);
        dialog.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(dialog);
```